# Trying to identify this rocker switch in a KRK speaker

Tags: switches

I am trying to replace a broken (the rocker arm was pushed in) rocker switch on a KRK V4 speaker, and am looking for a suitable part number. I don't see a number on the switch and don't want to take it off until I get a good part since the speaker still sort of works and I need to use them every day.

Can anyone identify this switch, or possible give me some keywords to search for, for example on digikey.com? I'm not sure what language to use for the form factor, poles, conductors, etc. As far as I can tell it is an on-off-on surface mount with the voltage in the pictures, and there are 6 conductors exposed. See images below, thanks!

[image: Photo 1]
[image: Photo 2]
[image: Photo 3]

**UPDATE: Added fourth photo with board layout**

[image]

Comment: That's right-angle, not surface mount. And I'm reasonably sure it's DPCO.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ebay.com/itm/C-K-7201-ON-ON-Mini-Toggle-DPDT-Right-Angle-Lot-of-5-/251162733932?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a7a772d6c

Actually saw this a little while ago today. Hope this is what you want?

I think you can find cheaper ones on ebay as well.

Comment: No center-off means that's not it.

Comment: [This one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/C-K-7203-ON-OFF-ON-Mini-Toggle-SPDT-Right-Angle-Long-Lever-Lot-of-5/261108631188?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D27538%26meid%3D9bc754f8e69d4dcf80a431812aa4a675%26pid%3D100005%26prg%3D11353%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D251162733932&rt=nc) has center off

Answer (score 0):

Search for a DPDT toggle switch with right-angle through hole mounting and an on-off-on function.

Doing [this search on DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv130=4&pv235=2&pv69=367&FV=fff40011%2Cfff80064&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) turns up several switches that may work.  This one looks similar to the one in your photo:

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/7203MD9ABE/CKN1484-ND/483859

A [search on Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Electromechanical/Switches/Toggle-Switches/_/N-5g2j?P=1z0z2xkZ1z0z2qcZ1z0z63vZ1z0z48oZ1yzuycrZ1z0z63xZ1z0wbs1&Keyword=dpdt&FS=True) also turns up many possibilities.

Comment: C&K and NKK (and probably others) make switches like that.